# Swift: Breakpoint in CoreData library

Tags: xcode, debugging, core-data, swift

XCode 6 Beta 3 using Swift.

In my App I use CoreData. When I run my App in simulator, XCode pops up the debugger with a breakpoint set somewhere in the CoreData library (see screenshot). This happens on several CoreData functions, for example when inserting new records or fetching records from an entity. The breakpoint position is always the same.

[image]

This is extremely annoying. When my App fetches 10 records from an entity I have to push the *continue program execution* button 10 times.

Because this breakpoint is set somewhere in machine code, the breakpoint inspector does not show any breakpoints so I cannot delete it.

Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Many thanks.

---

**Edit:**
backtrace-output:

> (lldb) bt
>   * thread #1: tid = 0x1d68b0, 0x000000010a2f7fcd libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
>     * frame #0: 0x000000010a2f7fcd libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
>       frame #1: 0x000000010a0fbb85 GPS Track`GPS_Track.TrackListTableViewController.tableView (tableView=<unavailable>)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.UITableView>, cellForRowAtIndexPath : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.NSIndexPath>) -> Swift.Optional<ObjectiveC.UITableViewCell> + 1125 at TrackListTableViewController.swift:53
>       frame #2: 0x000000010a0fc937 GPS Track`@objc GPS_Track.TrackListTableViewController.tableView (GPS_Track.TrackListTableViewController)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, cellForRowAtIndexPath : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> Swift.Optional + 87 at TrackListTableViewController.swift:0
>       frame #3: 0x000000010bc2f218 UIKit`-[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
>       frame #4: 0x000000010bc0f340 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2845
>       frame #5: 0x000000010bc24fea UIKit`-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
>       frame #6: 0x000000010bbb1ebd UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 519
>       frame #7: 0x000000010b9c9598 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
>       frame #8: 0x000000010b9be1be QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 380
>       frame #9: 0x000000010b9be02e QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 24
>       frame #10: 0x000000010b92cf16 QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 242
>       frame #11: 0x000000010b92e022 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 390
>       frame #12: 0x000000010b92e68d QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 89
>       frame #13: 0x000000010ab52927 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
>       frame #14: 0x000000010ab52880 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
>       frame #15: 0x000000010ab480d3 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1123
>       frame #16: 0x000000010ab47a06 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
>       frame #17: 0x000000010e9e9abf GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
>       frame #18: 0x000000010bb39cf8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
>       frame #19: 0x000000010a0e6a5d GPS Track`top_level_code + 77 at AppDelegate.swift:36
>       frame #20: 0x000000010a0e6a9a GPS Track`main + 42 at AppDelegate.swift:0
>       frame #21: 0x000000010d2e7145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
>   (lldb)

Comment: @akashivskyy: Sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: Could you post the full backtrace, which you get in the console? (if not, type `bt` when the break occurs)

Comment: this is crash not breakpoint.You need to provide backtrace to solve problem.Please type `bt` after (lldb) in console and copy and paste in your question

Comment: edited my post to include the backtrace

Comment: No breakpoints at all in my code

Comment: Do you Added an exception breakpoint? Contrary to Apple's best practices CoreData uses exceptions in the normal flow of control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tracked it down further: The problem only occurs when using custom object classes for the entities. Example:

```
// User class, defined in User.swift
class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var firstname: String
}


// --------------
// code somewhere else
let users = moc.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

for object in users {
    let user = object as User   // <-- breakpoint fired here
        println(user.name)
    }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

One need to make the custom object class visible to Objective C using the @objc directive:

```
// User class, defined in User.swift
@objc(User)    // <-- required!
class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var firstname: String
}
```

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Would be interesting to know: do you have to say `@objc(User)` or would it be sufficient to say `@objc` alone?

Comment: I was already doing that, I'm still hitting that break point.

Comment: @matt @zisoft I tried using the `@objc` keyword alone and it only worked for me in my subclass when I called out the class specifically like `@objc(User)`

Comment: @WorkingDev Very useful to know, thanks for that report!

Comment: @zisoft I have tried adding the @objc(CLASS) to the .swift file and I am still hitting the breakpoint. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: Same problem as @StePrescott -- still hitting the breakpoint :/

Comment: @ctietze I had the same issue:

You can fix it by going to your CoreData Model, Select the Entity and make sure you also populate the class name in the designer (it is blank by default).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an All Exception breakpoint set?

[image]

Contrary to Apple's best practices CoreData uses exceptions in the normal flow of control.

If you add exception breakpoints you may break in CoreData. The solution is to remove or disable the exception breakpoint.

Comment: Yep this worked, although annoyingly it's not ideal. As I'd like to listen to All Exceptions, just valid ones only ;)

Comment: Same here, is there a way to disable only this kind of exception? Even with all breakpoints disabled, the tests break at every type casts, but only in the test environment...

Answer (score 2):

While the above answers all are technically correct

@zisoft is right, however if you're using custom NSManagedObject classes then you should always use @objc(User), not just because of this break point.

@Zaph may work also, as you're essentially not listening and if indeed it's a bug it should stop it from appearing

However you may still hit this kind of break point if you're not type checking. I suspect it's a breakpoint in the beta 4  but will become a crash in the next beta.

I solved the issue in my code as I was hitting on returning the managed object received from insertNewObjectForEntityForName as AnyObject and later saying as myclass when I used it. Fine as I knew it was my class. but actualy should have done something like this

```
func createMyEntity() -> MyClass{ 
   if  let entity : MyClass = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MyClass", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as? MyClass
    {
        return entity;
    } 
    return nil;
}
```

Obviously that's just one example, but if you're the hitting the break point in other places then hopefully this a good reference.

Not withstanding this still may just be a bug in beta 4 of xcode, but this is safer anyway.

Update -- It also checking that your data model class name matches as it later through a warning here an this may also be why the breakpoint was hit.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my version of this problem based on info in  https://devforums.apple.com/message/1016337#1016337

- make the `NSManagedObject`-derived class and its relevant properties `public`
- do not include its source file in the test target's Compile Sources
- import the app target in the test file -- *e.g.*, `import MyApp` in `MyClassTests.swift`

Answer (score 2):

In your Core Data `*.xcdatamodeld` file, prefix your entity's class name with your app name. It should look something like this when you're done:

[image: entity class name prefix]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the last helped!!!

- make the NSManagedObject-derived class and its relevant properties public
- do not include its source file in the test target's Compile Sources
- import the app target in the test file -- e.g., import MyApp in MyClassTests.swift

Answer (score 0):

Following helped me ! 
If I undone one of this settings the breakpoint error comes again !

1. You have to set for your Entity-Model in your *Model.xcdatamodeld in property "Class" the same Name   example: Name=Chat   Class=Chat
2. You have to add Code **@objc(yourClass)** above your class

Pictures 1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoxtu.png

Pictures 2:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkYYq.png

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using `Xcode 6.2`

- Make `@objc` changes to your class i.e `@objc(className)`
- Next go to `*.xcdatamodeld` -> `Configurations` (Default if nothing specified) -> add class against entity