# @objc(ClassName) for subclasses of NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, swift

Is it necessary to add the `@objc` attribute to classes that extend `NSManagedObject`? As in:

```
@objc(Note)
class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var text: String
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

I've seen this in a few code samples, but with no explanation on why it is necessary and what it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was necessary on earlier (beta) versions of Xcode, I had a problem with that, see my question on SO: [Swift Breakpoint in CoreData library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841856/swift-breakpoint-in-coredata-library) and the solution I posted.

As of current versions of Xcode it seems to not be necessary any longer, so I removed the `@objc` from my code.