# Swift dynamic cast exception

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Does anyone know why I am getting the exception at this code block:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ListCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ListTableViewCell
    let item = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as List
    cell.list_name?.text = item.list_name
    return cell
}
```

Here is the custom class I am casting to:

```
   import UIKit
   import CoreData

  class List: NSManagedObject {
      @NSManaged var list_name: String
      @NSManaged var items: NSSet
  }
```

The exception happens at this line:

```
    let item = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as List
```

Here is the exception:

```
`libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional:
0x10d630860:  pushq  %rbp
0x10d630861:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10d630864:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x10d630867:  je     0x10d63089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10d630869:  movabsq $-0x7fffffffffffffff, %rax
0x10d630873:  testq  %rax, %rdi
0x10d630876:  jne    0x10d63089e               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 62
0x10d630878:  leaq   0xb52e9(%rip), %rax
0x10d63087f:  movq   (%rax), %rax
0x10d630882:  andq   (%rdi), %rax
0x10d630885:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
0x10d630890:  cmpq   %rsi, %rax
0x10d630893:  je     0x10d6308ad               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 77
0x10d630895:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
0x10d630899:  testq  %rax, %rax
0x10d63089c:  jne    0x10d630890               ; swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional + 48
0x10d63089e:  leaq   0x36b7d(%rip), %rax       ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x10d6308a5:  movq   %rax, 0xb4c0c(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x10d6308ac:  int3   
0x10d6308ad:  movq   %rdi, %rax
0x10d6308b0:  popq   %rbp
0x10d6308b1:  retq   
0x10d6308b2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)`
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: And where does it happen?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - What do you mean "where"?

Comment: @Dario - I have added the exception to the posting. Does that help out?

Comment: @J0NNYZER0 What line causes the exception? The whole program in its entirety doesn't throw the exception; there's a certain line that it happens on.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - Sorry I wasn't clear on that - let item = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as List

Comment: I don't know Swift. Is `as` a dynamic cast? Are you sure that whatever `objectAtIndexPath` returns is convertible to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object being returned by `objectAtIndexPath(_)` isn't a `List`.

You should always use *conditional* casting if it's not *guaranteed* to be `List`, like so:

```
if let item = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? List {
    // item is a List
    cell.list_name?.text = item.list_name
} else {
    // item isn't a List
    // See what it is if you're not expecting this
}
```

Comment: My List is a custom class. objectAtIndexPath(_) can be AnyObject. Shouldn't that allow it to be able to handle my List

Comment: Now I get this exception in the console: 
2015-03-21 18:42:50.518 MyList[29808:1235523] CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'MyList.List' for entity 'List'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

Comment: So I don't know why but most tutorials instruct me to apply the app name plus a dot before the class in the class field in the entity editor but when I removed this and just put in the class name in the class field of the entity editor it worked fine.

Comment: @J0NNYZER0 Your Core Data question is a good one but it's different than the one you asked here. If you search Stack Overflow and don't find the answer, feel free to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add

```
@objc(List)
```

over this line:

```
class List: NSManagedObject ...
```

This was the solution posted in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24844968/1514727).