# Breakpoint in Thread in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have no breakpoints defined, respectively I have deleted all existing breakpoint. 
Nevertheless it stops at a specific point, which I do not understand. It is not in my code. Its more lowlevel on a thread ? See screenshot.

How can I avoid that ?

[image]

Additional Info /Code:

It seems to stop at the getter of "LastselectedObject2"

```
0x10b5a0efc <Prototypes.Timelineview.LastselectedObject2.getter : Prototypes.DisplayedObject+12>: movq   0x76215(%rip), %rax       ; direct field offset for Prototypes.Timelineview.LastselectedObject2
```

it was forced with following code:

```
println("touchesBegan at start . LastObject :" + self.timelineview.LastselectedObject2.sTitle);
```

LastselectedObject2 is defined in the timelineview class:

```
class Timelineview: UIView {

    var LastselectedObject2:DisplayedObject;
...
...
```

The Class DisplayedObject looks as follow:

```
class DisplayedObject: NSObject, NSCopying  {

    var iType:Int = 0; // 0 = Phase ; 1 = Event
    var X1:Int = 0;
    var Y1:Int = 0;
    var X2:Int = 0;
    var Y2:Int = 0;
    var sWikiID:String = "";
    var sTitle:String = "";
    var sImage:String = "";

    var bclickable:Bool = true;

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {

        let a=DisplayedObject(iType: iType, X1: X1, Y1: Y1, X2: X2, Y2: Y2, sWikiID: sWikiID, sTitle: sTitle, sImage: sImage, bclickable: bclickable);

        //let theCopy = self.dynamicType(iType: iType, X1: X1, Y1: Y1, X2: X2, Y2: Y2, sWikiID: sWikiID, sTitle: sTitle, sImage: sImage, bclickable: bclickable);
        //theCopy.color = self.color
        return a

        //return DisplayedObject();
    }

    override init(){
        //self.iType=iType;
    }

    init(iType:Int, X1:Int,Y1:Int,X2:Int,Y2:Int, sWikiID:String, sTitle:String, sImage:String, bclickable:Bool){
        self.iType=iType;
        self.X1=X1;
        self.Y1=Y1;
        self.X2=X2;
        self.Y2=Y2;
        self.sWikiID=sWikiID;
        self.sTitle=sTitle;
        self.sImage=sImage;
        self.bclickable=bclickable;
    }

    func empty(){
        X1 = 0;
        iType = 0; // 0 = Phase ; 1 = Event
        X1 = 0;
        Y1 = 0;
        X2 = 0;
        Y2 = 0;
        sWikiID = "";
        sTitle = "";
        sImage = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code !! Its not related to breakpoint, its because of code.

Comment: Thanks ! I added relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with CoreData objects, see my post: [Swift: Breakpoint in CoreData Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841856/swift-breakpoint-in-coredata-library)

Try to make the class visible to ObjectiveC:

```
@objc(DisplayedObject)
class DisplayedObject: NSObject, NSCopying  {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but @object(DisplayedObject) did not help.

Comment: Should be `@objc(DisplayedObject)`, not `@object(DisplayedObject)`

Comment: Sorry. I misstyped here in stackoverflow, but tested with @objc(DisplayedObject). It still stops at the same point.